# When does save_post hook fire on post save/update

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

In my plugin I want to update sitemap every time **page** or **post** is created/modified. To achieve this I use `save_post` hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_sitemap', 10, 3);
```

Upon creating/saving/updating/deleting any **page** my callback method `update_sitemap` is fired but when i create/save/update/delete any **post** it doesn't seem to fire callback `update_sitemap` immediately.

I tested this for custom post types and it works immediately like for pages.

When I add 2 new regular posts, callback method is called once. Only after any further modification callback for 2nd post is fired.

Is this expected behaviour for `save_post` hook?

Comment: It's impossible to guess what the `update_sitemap()` function do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_post` is fired at the end of `wp_insert_post()` which is the core function that's run whenever a post is inserted or updated (`wp_update_post()` calls it internally). This includes when the post is updated via the classic editor and the block editor (Gutenberg), as well whenever it's updated via the REST API. The only reason it wouldn't fire is if the post was being updated via SQL directly (via a plugin or otherwise), or when only post meta is updated via a function.

So no, this is not the expected behaviour. If your function isn't firing then it could be interference from another theme or plugin, or it could be an issue with the function itself, but there's not enough information in the question to say either way.